# Problems while upgrading inter.broker.protocol.version from '2.3-IV1' to newer versions

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Came across an issue: *...Version 3.5 is not a valid version`* while trying to upgrade from Confluent Kafka v5.5.1 to v7.5.1

Hello all. I have the Confluentinc Kafka single test broker deployed onto OCP4. Task is to upgrade from the ConfluentInc cp-enterprise-kafka v5.5.1(Kavka v2.3.0-IV1) to cp-kafka v7.5.1(Kafka v3.5.0).
Upgrading in accordance to https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_3_5_0 .

Initial config(Kafka is up and running):

```
confluentinc image: source.url/confluentinc/cp-kafka
confluentinc imageTag: 7.5.1
server property inter.broker.protocol.version: "2.3-IV1"
log.message.format.version: "2.3-IV1"
```

Updated config(error, see below):

```
confluentinc image: same
confluentinc imageTag: same
server property inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.5"
#omitting the log.message.format.version for 3.*
```

Issue: *Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 3.5 for configuration inter.broker.protocol.version: Version 3.5 is not a valid version`*

UPD:
Similar error occurs while trying to upgrade more gradually to *v6.0.5*
(pls see the Confluent vs Broker protocol versions vs message format versions compatibility table from https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/upgrade.html#steps-for-upgrading-to-version-x-zk-mode):

```
confluentinc image: source.url/confluentinc/cp-kafka
confluentinc imageTag: 6.0.5
server property inter.broker.protocol.version: "2.6"
server property log.message.format.version: "2.6"
```

Issue: *Invalid value 2.6 for configuration inter.broker.protocol.version: Version 2.6 is not a valid version`*

Comment: It is not recommended to skip major versions. Upgrade to 6.x first

Comment: @OneCricketeer ty, updated. The issue still occurs for v6.*

Comment: I suggest reaching out to Confluent Support, then (you should have a license contract to use the `enterprise` image) since that version is indeed valid to Apache - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_6_0 ; And I was suggesting `6.2.x`, rather than `6.0.x`, but I assume you'd see same for 2.8. I've never upgraded Kafka using Docker, we always ran on AWS VMs